# Where to find Kelly's thesis on Weighted Shifts on Hilbert Space?

Tags: reference-request, operator-theory

I am reading about weighted shifts on a hilbert space. So many of the books/ papers list R.L. Kelly's paper Weighted Shifts on Hilbert Space as a reference that I really want to have a look at this paper.

However, since it is a thesis when he was a student at UMichigan, in 1966, it seems there is no way I can find this paper.
And a search on the net gives no results.

I wonder whether someone knows how to get this paper. Thanks very much!

Comment: I'm not sure about UM's library policy, but at some universities, if a paper or book is not already in electronic format, you can request that they scan it and email it to you, and it seems like UM does have this thesis on hand: http://mirlyn.lib.umich.edu/Record/002147685.  But, of course, you need to be affiliated with the school, or at least have a friend who is and will do this for you.

Comment: Actually, I am not sure about having to be affiliated with UM. In fact, if Hui is affiliated with *some* academic department, he can try requesting it through his home university library. Hui, talk to your librarian.

Comment: Here's the [MathSciNet entry](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2616225) for this thesis which in turn links [here](http://proquest.umi.com/pqdlink?did=757986581&Fmt=7&clientId=79356&RQT=309&VName=PQD). I would try interlibrary loan.